# Designing a code autocompletion system

Tags: algorithm, parsing, data-structures

I would like to design an autocompletion system for a custom scripting language that I am building. I have some ideas but they are not complete. Should I go for generating possible strings from the grammar of the parser or is there some other simpler method?

Comment: use a trie. But it depends a lot on the number of strings you have. You can also consider suffix trees, they take a lot less space than tries. But, still, give us more clarity on your exact requirements and maybe we can be of more help

Comment: Thanks!!                                                                                                       
I had thought of tries before but I am trying to implement something more intelligent here. A trie is a great choice but its essentially a finite automata. I am looking for a system which can do smarter things like suggesting a closing brace in a valid situation if braces are unbalanced and so on(maybe a pda). I know it's not that easy however I am trying to build a minimalistic language, so it may be possible.